# Why Can't I access this method with an instance reference?

Tags: c#, events

I'm trying to log user inactivity, however when I try to call the method which gets the system Idle time it throws an error saying

```
"Member 'NotifyIcon.Inactivity.GetIdleTime()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"
```

this is my custom event for getting user Idle time

```
private void Inactivity_Inactive(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    inactivity.GetIdleTime();
}
```

and the method with the code to get the idle time

```
public static uint GetIdleTime()
{
    LASTINPUTINFO lastInput = new LASTINPUTINFO();
    lastInput.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInput);
    GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInput);

    return (uint)Environment.TickCount - lastInput.dwTime;
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static methods do not need an instance reference to the object of their class in order to run, because they do not reference any of the non-static fields, properties, or methods.

When C# compiler detects you calling `static` methods on an object reference, it suspects that you wanted to call some other method, and issues the error that you see.

Replace

```
inactivity.GetIdleTime();
```

with

```
NotifyIcon.Inactivity.GetIdleTime();
```

to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

No need for **instance** reference with static methods.

Try this:

```
NotifyIcon.Inactivity.GetIdleTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

`public static uint GetIdleTime()` is not an instance method.

Instead you need to call:

```
NotifyIcon.Inactivity.GetIdleTime();
```